# Iframe fail to Run

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, html

I want to display a video using `iFrame` such as:

```
<tr>
            <td class="style3" style="width: 50%">
            </td>
            <td class="style3" style="width: 50%">

               <iframe id="frame1" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Kk-yZ7VpeA" runat="server" style="height: 222px; width: 482px"  ></iframe>

            </td>
        </tr>
```

But its not able to run while run. what particular code i am missing or is there any error  with the code. thanks for any assistence.

Comment: What do you see ? nothing at all ? what is render on html.... maybe if you remove the runat=server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the following embed link in your iframe for youtube videos:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/#VIDEO_ID#
```

So it will be

```
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/3Kk-yZ7VpeA"
```

Also see http://jsfiddle.net/QsQEP/

Comment: yes sir, now its working .. i have replace that with a new URL and it contains embed .thanks sir

Answer (score 0):

its work now.. i have changed the Url and its started working. Don't know what was basically a problem. anyhow thanks